# Why can't transfer info from html li tag to jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to transfer information from my LI to jQuery function but I get undefined:

The HTML code

```
"<li id='" + obj[i].ID + "' itemid='"+obj[i].Name+"'>" + obj[i].Name + "</li>";//info from an array name obj, works fine in li.
```

the jquery code:

```
 var array = [];
            var $elem = $(this);
            $elem.each(function (i) {
                $('li', this).each(function (e) {
                    array.push(this.id,this.itemid); // this.id works, **this.item - undefined**                  
                });
```

Also I tried to create a special attribute to transfer my info from the li to jQuery function, but no change.(itemid is a LI attribute)

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
"<li id='" + obj[i].ID + "' data-itemid='"+obj[i].Name+"'>" + obj[i].Name + "</li>";
```

JavaSscript:

```
var array = [];
var $elem = $(this);
$elem.each(function (i) {
    $('li', this).each(function (e) {
        array.push(this.id, $(this).data('itemid'));
    });
```

The reason `this.itemid` does not is work is that it is not a valid html attribute. Using data-* is the correct way of passing data as element attributes.

Comment: Thank you for giving an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I like [jammykam's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140761/2084), but if you don't want to change your HTML you could use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jQuery method to get the value of itemid attribute:

```
array.push(this.id, $(this).attr('itemid'));
```